# What's a good resource explaining the best ways to buy Bitcoin (noob friendly)?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins

We have a slew of questions about specific regions ... but I couldn't find a general, concise, good resource on how to buy Bitcoins.

[This article](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins) offers too many choices and isn't noob friendly.

I want to link to the answer from the [Newbie Guide](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Newbie_Guide) I'm making.

An answer to this question **should not be a specific way to buy** (it will get stale, Stack Exchange does not handle staleness issues very well), but rather **an external resource that is maintained and up to date** (and will likely remain so in the future). I suggest a new Wiki entry that is noob friendly.

**Update**: [I've opened up a new wiki entry for this](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_Bitcoins_%28the_noob_version%29), you can help edit it.

Comment: See this similar question for guidelines - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4178/what-is-a-good-resource-to-help-newbies-choose-their-first-wallet-s

Comment: Also http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-do-you-obtain-bitcoins

Comment: WAY too confusing. We need a step-by-step, especially for US residents who aren't used to, and maybe never have, exchanged any money. I have seen both wiki entries, while I sit on 2 bank accounts, debit cards, and a prepaid credit card. Why don't I have any @#$%^&*&^% bitcoins two #$%^&* hours ago? Why is the process so $$%^&^& difficult? I just want to key in my cc and buy some bitcoins. Why can't I do that?

Comment: A link to some information on wallet choinces is here: [http://bitxoin.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/bitcoin-newbies-start-here.html](http://bitxoin.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/bitcoin-newbies-start-here.html)

Comment: LocalBitcons.com offers over-simplified guide in 6 languages on their site: https://localbitcoins.com/landing/en/ They aim to coverage all regions, payment methods and languages, so it should be pretty much non-US-focused there.

Answer (score 6):

A guide almost needs to be one that provides results dynamically based on responses to questions.

The factors that matter are:

- Where are you (country)?
- How much are you looking to buy?
- What payment methods can you use?
- How soon do you need the bitcoins?
- Is privacy / near-anonymity important?

Only once those are known can recommendations be made.

A fairly comprehensive list of methods exist on the Bitcoin wiki:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins

Answer (score 2):

http://howdoyoubuybitcoins.com/

Seems to be attempting to provide this info and keep it up to date.

Comment: The linked page seems to be not working anymore. There is however now [howtobuybitcoins.info](http://howtobuybitcoins.info), which seems to provide similar information or might even be the new site for the same webpage.