# Where to find a people who have bitcoins, to exchange USD to BTC with no KYC offline?

Tags: exchanges, offline, community, fiat

I have cash in USD, i want to buy BTC in my city, but i don't want to buy it with exchange magazine, because bad exchange rate and because it requires KYC and i'm not want to my personal data will leak and someone will fake my person.

What i should do to find a people who have a BTC and ready to exchange it to my USD cash?

I think i should find some miners in miners communities, but i don't know where i should looking for.

p.s. I'm not interest to any online exchange, because i don't want to be scummed, i want to meet offline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started) which has a lot of useful links, one of which leads you to [How do you obtain Bitcoins](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/91/13866)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick unfortunately no. I've explore questions before write my own, nothing useful for me. This question are closer to mine, but answers not useful for me https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/whats-a-good-resource-explaining-the-best-ways-to-buy-bitcoin-noob-friendly. Answer about localbitcoins.com are good, but this service is not working anymore

Comment: Note that service recommendations are off-topic here, because the answers tend to get outdated quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Service recommendations are off-topic here, but more generally, you can just look around online to find out if there are any local bitcoin meetup groups in your area. Attend a meetup, talk to some people, ask if anyone is willing to sell some bitcoin. Thats really all it takes.