# Is there a wallet app for iPhones?

Tags: wallet, mobile, ios

I have an android phone as I can not afford an iPhone, but my friend has an iPhone. I am using Bitcoin Wallet from Andreas Schildbach and it's really easy. Is there something like that for the iPhone as we can't seem to find it?

Comment: related: [What is a good resource to help newbies choose their first wallet/s?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4178/5406)

Comment: A bit late, but you may find this article informative. Or look for others on the same subject, there was actually a news frenzy when this happened.
http://readwrite.com/2014/02/06/apple-blockchain-last-bitcoin-wallet-ios-app-store-iphone

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not allow Bitcoin wallet applications on its devices.

Comment: Theoretically, a jail-broken iPhone should still be able to use any of the old wallets now kicked-off the app-store, right?

Comment: @JoePineda: I have no idea myself.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 (out of 30) awesome hot bitcoin wallets on App Store in 2021:

- [Coinbase](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/coinbase-wallet/id1278383455)
- [Exodus](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/exodus-crypto-bitcoin-wallet/id1414384820)
- [Mycelium](https://apps.apple.com/app/mycelium-bitcoin-wallet/id943912290)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no apps are allowed. Best you can do is just use a web browser.