# Which method/programme can create a wallet using the least amount of space?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet

On a first attempt to create a wallet with `bitcoind`, the process failed after filling the 160 Gb available in my home disk.

Which method or programme would allow me to create a wallet using the least space possible?

**Update**: I removed `bitcoind` and am now using Electrum. However, this freed up hardly any space on disk. How can I delete whatever files `bitcoind` created?

Comment: What do you need the wallet for? Do you just want to use it privately once a month, or are you building a service that needs to hear about every transaction within seconds?

Comment: A personal wallet for occasional use.

Comment: related: [What is a good resource to help newbies choose their first wallet/s?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4178/5406), [Where is the data folder for Bitcoin-Qt?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4006/5406)

Comment: Delete the old files from the location described here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/where-is-the-data-folder-for-bitcoin-qt

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to have its entire blockchain on your machine, depending on your situation:

You should clarify / update your question to include why you are running bitcoind from a command-line in the first place.

If you JUST want a wallet/Bitcoin-address, there are plenty of options.

I personally use "Electrum Bitcoin Wallet" GUI and find it easy to use - again your question is unclear so this may not be your complete answer but should provide a start.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running a bitcoind server, you can enable pruning. This means only a part of the blockchain is saved.

[How can I run bitcoind in pruning mode?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37496/how-can-i-run-bitcoind-in-pruning-mode)