# Should I use bitpay?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, electrum, bitpay, copay

Looking to store .145 of bitcoin in a strong wallet. Should I use Bitpay for this? If not, please recommend better wallets. No hardware wallets please, I am trying to save money.

Comment: related: [What is a good resource to help newbies choose their first wallet/s?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4178/5406)

Answer (score 2):

Electrum (https://electrum.org) is a good choice if you wish to store your bitcoin locally on your PC.   Supports things like hardware wallets, multiple wallets, seed (longish string of words) to recover your wallet if it's lost, and you can later on export your keys and import them into another wallet if you prefer.