# What site should I use to create a Bitcoin wallet?

Tags: wallet, e-wallet

I wanted to create Bitcoin wallet but I saw there are a lot of websites or software to create it. It's not like paypal. 
I am thinking to chose Blockchain. Is it good? How to check if it's legal in my country?

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4178/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4178/5406

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend Jaxx wallet since, several weeks ago, it was found exploitable, [giving an attacker the possibility to retrive your 12 words seed .](https://vxlabs.com/2017/06/10/extracting-the-jaxx-12-word-wallet-backup-phrase/) 
Usually, you choose a service that gives you the full control and ownership of keys. Blockchain.info doesn't give you this option.
Some service I would recommend are [GreenAddress](https://greenaddress.it/) and Samurai Wallet.

Answer (score -2):

I am using Jaxx! I think it is good, because is platform agnostic and handle different digital currencies.

https://jaxx.io

Comment: Jaxx had security issues just weeks ago and they shrugged them off stating that they're satisfied with their security concept. See e.g.: https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/users-report-losing-400000-due-to-jaxx-wallet-vulnerability/ I don't think they're a good recommendation at this time.

Comment: Good to know. @Murch

Comment: @Murch what could be the best option, into the security perspective?

Comment: I prioritize security over features. I've used Bitcoin Core, Bitcoin Wallet App and Mycelium in the past. I've heard good things about Electrum and GreenAddress. Unfortunately, I don't have experience with any multicoin wallets.