# Bitcoin Wallet Question

Tags: accessibility

I have a nice sum of bitcoins in a particular account. The account is with a "bank" that does cryptocurrency conversion. This place is charging me $$$ for codes (IMF, COT, Tax, etc.).
I need a bitcoin wallet to access my cash without paying these ridiculous fees. Is the bitcoin wallet universal? I mean, can I obtain a bitcoin wallet from a third party; like through this site? Or, can I only get the bitcoin wallet from the "bank" where I have the account? I ask, because I need to access the bitcoins through bitcoin atm... Thanks.

Comment: Some services only allow you to trade exposure to Bitcoin, while others allow you to purchase bitcoins. The latter will let you withdraw to any Bitcoin wallet. You can find some pointers to pick a wallet on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4178/5406

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/i-am-new-to-bitcoin-how-can-i-get-started)