# How can I manually connect a bitcoin network and create a bitcoin account?

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, client, public-key, bitcoin-cli

I am not sure that I'm 100% technically correct, but I want to create a key value pair which is essentially my Bitcoin account.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

So what does it take me to make my record in the Bitcoin network manually, through a command line tool or by the means of a Python script?

I'm asking that out of a simple interest and I hope it will help me to understand the things in depth.

Answer (score 1):

Confusingly, software that manages a Bitcoin user's keyring is called a "wallet". There is no sign-up or registration of new keys, the keys only need to be generated locally. (Although, when you get paid, the sender locks up funds such that they can only be spent by using your key, so I guess that way your key would be recorded in the blockchain at that point.)

Either way, the easiest way to generate a key pair would be to download and run a Bitcoin Wallet. You can find some guidance on picking your first wallet in this topic: [What is a good resource to help newbies choose their first wallet/s?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4178/5406)

Comment: >so I guess that way your key would be recorded in the blockchain at that point - this was an essential input

Comment: In case it wasn't clear: your key doesn't get entered in a user registry or the like. Your public key is used to lock up funds so that only you can spend them when you get paid. So only keys that got paid are actually known on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I have my questions answered in this article:

https://medium.com/coinmonks/bitcoin-with-python-6595588c2fcf