# Which wallet is both convenient and safe for new unexperienced non-advanced user?

Tags: wallet

I consider myself as a new unexperienced non-advanced user. Even if I have got some amount of BTC in 2015.
I never used my BTC, and currently I have a very, very old wallet, the one which downloads terabites of data before BTC become available (don't remember its name). But the wallet itself is simple which I like. The todays wallets scare me by their complicity :-)
Which wallet would you advice to such an unexperienced person like me?
It should be safe, convenient, simple.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4178/5406

Comment: See https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet